# Util functions inside or outside services

Tags: nestjs

I am writing a lot of util functions.

Do I need to put them inside a Service or can I leave them outside?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilities are for static functionality that does not depend on a state. Once you call a function, it gets the job done and nothing further.

Services on the other hand can handle state and are usually more complex. You could have some kind of DownloadService that is initialized with an URL, then fetches it, and finally does some kind of post-processing.

As a rule of thumb, a utility does not have dependencies and does not call other (non-static) methods. Services are more complex and might call other services. Services may have an internal state.

As of now if your utils are not calling other services then it's good to have them outside.

It would be a better idea to leave them outside. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes my util functions do not use any state.Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.